# How do you assign different data sources for a DataGridViewComboBox for each record?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a winforms DataGridView that I wish to have a column containing comboboxes for each record. Each combobox will have completely different values for each row and need to be assigned a datasource during the databinding of the DataGridView.  I can assign 1 datasource to all (that's easy), but having each combobox have different values looks impossible).

Here's what I'm working with - note: The datasource of the DataGridView is defined programmatically by setting a property from the calling form.

```
Public Class frmSendToQuickbooksPopup

    Public Property CurrentOrder As OrderICT
    Public Property lineitems As List(Of OrderLineItemICT)

    Private Sub frmSendToQuickbooksPopup_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'define the combobox (datasource can't be assigned here as each will be different for each row)
        Dim dgvcboMatch As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        dgvcboMatch.DisplayMember = "Name"
        dgvcboMatch.ValueMember = "ListID"
        dgvcboMatch.HeaderText = "Matches"
        dgvcboMatch.Name = "Match"
        dgvcboMatch.Width = 150
        dgvLineItems.Columns.Add(dgvcboMatch)

        Me.dgvLineItems.DataSource = lineitems
    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvLineItems_DataSourceChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgvLineItems.DataSourceChanged
        Dim L As New QBI.OrderLineItemICT
        With L
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_LineItemBvin).Visible = False
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ProductId).Visible = False
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ProductShortDescription).Visible = False
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ShippingBoxCount).Visible = False
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_CustomProperties).Visible = False
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ShippingLength).Visible = False
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ShippingWidth).Visible = False
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ShippingHeight).Visible = False
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ProductName).DisplayIndex = 2
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ProductName).HeaderText = "Product Name"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ProductName).Width = 170
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ProductSku).HeaderText = "SKU"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ProductSku).Width = 160
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_Quantity).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n0"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_Quantity).DisplayIndex = 7
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_Quantity).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_Quantity).Width = 65
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_AdjustedPrice).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_AdjustedPrice).HeaderText = "Adj Price"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_AdjustedPrice).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_AdjustedPrice).Width = 80
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_BasePrice).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_BasePrice).HeaderText = "Base Price"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_BasePrice).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_BasePrice).Width = 85
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_Discounts).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_Discounts).HeaderText = "Discounts"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_Discounts).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_Discounts).Width = 80
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_LineTotal).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_LineTotal).HeaderText = "Line Total"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_LineTotal).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_LineTotal).Width = 80
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_UOM).DisplayIndex = 9
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_UOM).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_UOM).HeaderText = "Units"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_UOM).Width = 55
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ShippingWeight).DisplayIndex = 10
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ShippingWeight).HeaderText = "Unit Wt"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ShippingWeight).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N1"
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ShippingWeight).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            dgvLineItems.Columns(.col_ShippingWeight).Width = 70
        End With
    End Sub

Public Function GetComboboxData(ProductNameToMatch As String, ProductSKUToMatch As String) As List(Of WPM_Item)
    'this function returns a list of returned matches for a given row's ProductName or SKU
    'this function will be the datasource for a given combobox
    Dim itms As New List(Of WPM_Item)
    itms = WPM_Data.FindWPM_ItemMatch(ProductNameToMatch, ProductSKUToMatch)
    Return itms
End Function



End Class
```

If there were some way to intercept the databinding of the DataGridView so I can get a value from another cell (to call another procedure), then use the return data to populate each row's combobox. This is easy w/webforms, but I don't see an event for the winforms version.

---

Another thing I've tried, but does not work (the combobox datasource just disappears!)

```
Private Sub dgvLineItems_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles dgvLineItems.DataBindingComplete
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgvLineItems.Rows
        Dim dr = DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, OrderLineItemICT)
        If dr Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim name As String = row.Cells(dr.col_ProductName).Value.ToString
        Dim SKU As String = row.Cells(dr.col_ProductSku).Value.ToString

        Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = TryCast(row.Cells("Match"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        cell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox

        Dim wpm_items As List(Of WPM_Item) = GetComboboxData(name, SKU)
        If cell.DataSource Is Nothing Then
            cell.DataSource = wpm_items 'this forgets the datasource, why?
            cell.DisplayMember = "Name"
            cell.ValueMember = "ListID"
            cell.Value = wpm_items.Item(0).Name 'this always throws an error "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid."
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

---

Here's another version of that same assignment, this time the combobox is populated with the add method. (STILL does not remember the values)
I basically followed another forum's idea - maybe DotNet 4.5 DataGridView has a bug in it.

```
Private Sub dgvLineItems_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles dgvLineItems.DataBindingComplete
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgvLineItems.Rows
        Dim dr = DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, OrderLineItemICT)
        If dr Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim name As String = row.Cells(dr.col_ProductName).Value.ToString
        Dim SKU As String = row.Cells(dr.col_ProductSku).Value.ToString

        Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DirectCast(row.Cells("Match"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        cell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox

        Dim wpm_items As List(Of WPM_Item) = GetComboboxData(name, SKU)

        'THIS DOES NOT WORK EITHER!! 
        cell.DisplayMember = "Name"
        cell.ValueMember = "ListID"
        For Each wItm As WPM_Item In wpm_items
            Dim c As New comboboxitem
            c.Text = wItm.Name
            c.Value = wItm.ListID
            cell.Items.Add(c)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
Public Class ComboboxItem
    Public Property Text() As String
    Public Property Value() As Object

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Text
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allrighty Then! Here's a working solution. What I discovered is that you must create your DataGridView programmatically (tedious, yes!) and turn off auto-generation of columns (absolute must) - this prevents multiple firings of dataGridView events, for one. It also prevents losing your datasource for your combobox. Using the DataBindingComplete event and parsing the rows within is the best way to do this (CellFormatting event is overkill and is called w/every mouse move, click, resize, etc).
For those of us working with objects instead of datatables, I hope this solution is usable.

The code:

```
Imports QBI
Imports QBI.QBI
Imports QBI.AppCore.Xutilities

Public Class TestDGV1

    Public dgv1 As DataGridView

    Private Sub TestDGV1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim ordlineitems As List(Of OrderLineItemICT)
        ordlineitems = Order_DataICT.GetNewOrderLineItemsICT("26073bff-3a08-4bc2-8da9-79c75534bd6b")
        dgv1 = Me.CreateDGV(ordlineitems) 'create the DataGridView and save it as "dgv1" (which must be publically accessible)

        Me.SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(dgv1) 'NOTE, the datagridview is inside a SplitContainer
    End Sub

    Public Function CreateDGV(dsItems As List(Of OrderLineItemICT)) As DataGridView
        Dim dgv As New DataGridView()
        dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        dgv.DataSource = dsItems
        dgv.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = False

        Dim L As New QBI.OrderLineItemICT 'only using this reference for my column names defined elsewhere

        Dim col0 As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn With {.Name = "Match", .DataPropertyName = "NameMatch", .DisplayMember = "Name", .ValueMember = "ListID", .HeaderText = "Matches", .AutoComplete = True}
        col0.DisplayIndex = 0

        Dim col1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_LineItemBvin, .DataPropertyName = L.col_LineItemBvin, .Visible = False, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = L.col_LineItemBvin}
        col1.DisplayIndex = 1

        Dim col2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_ProductId, .DataPropertyName = L.col_ProductId, .Visible = False, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = L.col_ProductId}
        col2.DisplayIndex = 2

        Dim col3 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_ProductSku, .DataPropertyName = L.col_ProductSku, .Visible = True, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = "SKU"}
        col3.DisplayIndex = 3
        col3.Width = 160
        Dim col4 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_Quantity, .DataPropertyName = L.col_Quantity, .Visible = True, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = "QTY"}
        col4.DisplayIndex = 9
        col4.Width = 65
        col4.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n0"
        col4.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        Dim col5 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_BasePrice, .DataPropertyName = L.col_BasePrice, .Visible = True, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = "Base Price"}
        col5.DisplayIndex = 6
        col5.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
        col5.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        col5.Width = 85

        Dim col6 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_Discounts, .DataPropertyName = L.col_Discounts, .Visible = True, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = "Discounts"}
        col6.DisplayIndex = 7
        col6.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
        col6.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        col6.Width = 80

        Dim col7 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_AdjustedPrice, .DataPropertyName = L.col_AdjustedPrice, .Visible = True, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = "Adj Price"}
        col7.DisplayIndex = 8
        col7.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
        col7.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        col7.Width = 80

        Dim col8 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_LineTotal, .DataPropertyName = L.col_LineTotal, .Visible = True, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = "Line Total"}
        col8.DisplayIndex = 11
        col8.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2"
        col8.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        col8.Width = 80

        Dim col9 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_ProductName, .DataPropertyName = L.col_ProductName, .Visible = True, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = "Product Name"}
        col9.DisplayIndex = 4
        col9.Width = 170

        Dim col10 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_ProductShortDescription, .DataPropertyName = L.col_ProductShortDescription, .Visible = False, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = L.col_ProductShortDescription}
        col10.DisplayIndex = 5

        Dim col11 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_ShippingWeight, .DataPropertyName = L.col_ShippingWeight, .Visible = True, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = "Unit Wt"}
        col11.DisplayIndex = 12
        col11.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N1"
        col11.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        col11.Width = 70
        Dim col12 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_ShippingWidth, .DataPropertyName = L.col_ShippingWidth, .Visible = False, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = L.col_ShippingWidth}
        col12.DisplayIndex = 13

        Dim col13 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_ShippingHeight, .DataPropertyName = L.col_ShippingHeight, .Visible = False, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = L.col_ShippingHeight}
        col13.DisplayIndex = 14

        Dim col14 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_ShippingBoxCount, .DataPropertyName = L.col_ShippingBoxCount, .Visible = False, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = L.col_ShippingBoxCount}
        col14.DisplayIndex = 15

        Dim col15 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_CustomProperties, .DataPropertyName = L.col_CustomProperties, .Visible = False, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = L.col_CustomProperties}
        col15.DisplayIndex = 16

        Dim col16 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = L.col_UOM, .DataPropertyName = L.col_UOM, .Visible = True, .ReadOnly = True, .HeaderText = "Units"}
        col16.DisplayIndex = 10
        col16.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        col16.Width = 55

        dgv.Columns.AddRange({col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15, col16})

        AddHandler dgv.DataBindingComplete, AddressOf dgvLineItems_DataBindingComplete

        Return dgv
    End Function

    Private Sub dgvLineItems_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgv1.Rows
            Dim dr = DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, OrderLineItemICT)
            If dr Is Nothing Then
                Return
            End If

            Dim name As String = row.Cells(dr.col_ProductName).Value.ToString
            Dim SKU As String = row.Cells(dr.col_ProductSku).Value.ToString
            Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DirectCast(row.Cells("Match"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
            Dim wpm_items As List(Of WPM_Item) = GetComboboxData(name, SKU) 'function inside
            If cell.DataSource Is Nothing Then
                cell.DataSource = wpm_items 
                cell.DisplayMember = "Name"
                cell.ValueMember = "ListID"
                cell.Value = cell.Items(0).ListID
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function GetComboboxData(ProductNameToMatch As String, ProductSKUToMatch As String) As List(Of WPM_Item)
        'this function returns a list of returned matches for a given row's ProductName or SKU
        'this function will be the datasource for a given combobox
        Dim itms As New List(Of WPM_Item)
        itms = WPM_Data.FindWPM_ItemMatch(ProductNameToMatch, ProductSKUToMatch)
        Return itms
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example in C# on how to have a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in a `DataGridView` with different `Types`.

```
public static class ComboColumnDemo {

    public static DataGridView CreateSampleDGV() {

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("VariableType", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("VariableId", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Custom", typeof(Object));
        table.Columns.Add("Default", typeof(Object));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        table.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "int", 0, null, null, DateTime.MinValue });
        table.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "decimal", 0, null, null, DateTime.MinValue });
        table.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "enum", 0, null, null, DateTime.Now });
        table.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "date", 0, null, null, DateTime.UtcNow });
        table.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "person", 0, null, null, DateTime.Today });
        table.Rows.Add(new Object[] { "String", 0, null, null, DateTime.MaxValue });

        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        dgv.DataSource = table;
        dgv.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colComboDefault = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn { DataPropertyName = "Default", MaxDropDownItems = 20 };
        //col2.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing; //.DropDownButton;
        colComboDefault.AutoComplete = true;
        colComboDefault.ValueType = typeof(Object);

        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { DataPropertyName = "VariableType" });
        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { DataPropertyName = "VariableId" });
        dgv.Columns.Add(colComboDefault);
        dgv.Columns.Add(new CalendarColumn { DataPropertyName = "Date" });

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dgv.Columns)
            c.HeaderText = c.DataPropertyName;

        List<Object> strings = new List<Object>(new [] { "a", "b", "c" });
        var ints = new List<Object>(new Object[] { DBNull.Value, 1, 2, 3 });
        var decimals = new List<Object>(new Object[] { 1111111m, 2222222m, 3333333m });
        List<Object> dates = new List<Object>(new Object[] { DBNull.Value, DateTime.Today });
        List<Object> enums = new List<object>();
        enums.Add(DBNull.Value);
        enums.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<Object>().ToArray());

        DataTable enumsTable = Opulos.Core.Utils.EnumUtil<DayOfWeek>.ToDataTable();

        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

        dgv.CellFormatting += (sender, e) => {
            var drv = (DataRowView) dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
            if (drv == null)
                return;

            DataRow dr = drv.Row;
            //String colName = dgv.Columns[col2].DataPropertyName;

            String vt = (String) dr["VariableType"]; //table.Rows[row][0].ToString();
            if (vt == "decimal" && e.ColumnIndex == 2) {
                if (e.Value is decimal) {
                    e.Value = ((decimal) e.Value).ToString("n0");
                    e.FormattingApplied = true;
                }
            }
        };

        dgv.CellBeginEdit += (sender, e) => {
        //dgv.EditingControlShowing += delegate {
            int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;//dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            int colIndex = e.ColumnIndex; //dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            DataGridViewColumn col = dgv.Columns[colIndex];

            try {
                var drv = (DataRowView) dgv.Rows[rowIndex].DataBoundItem;
                if (drv == null)
                    return;

                DataRow dr = drv.Row;
                //String colName = dgv.Columns[col2].DataPropertyName;

                String vt = (String) dr["VariableType"]; //table.Rows[row][0].ToString();
                //String vt = vm.VariableType;

                Object items = null;
                ComboBoxStyle? style = null;
                Type valueType = null;
                String formatString = null;
                String displayMember = null;
                String valueMember = null;

                if (vt == "String") {
                    items = strings;
                    valueType = typeof(String);
                }
                else if (vt == "int") {
                    items = ints;
                    valueType = typeof(int);
                }
                else if (vt == "decimal") {
                    items = decimals;
                    formatString = "n0";
                    valueType = typeof(decimal);
                }
                else if (vt == "date") {
                    items = dates;
                    valueType = typeof(DateTime);
                }
                else if (vt == "enum") {
                    if (col == colComboDefault) {
                        items = enumsTable;
                        displayMember = "Display";
                        valueMember = "Value";
                    }
                    else
                        items = enums;
                    style = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
                    valueType = typeof(DayOfWeek);
                }
                else if (vt == "person") {
                    items = persons;
                    valueType = typeof(Person);
                }

                if (col == colComboDefault) {
                    var cell2 = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell) dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex];
                    cell2.DataSource = items;
                    cell2.ValueType = valueType;
                    cell2.DisplayMember = displayMember;
                    cell2.ValueMember = valueMember;
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(dgv.FindForm(), ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        };

        return dgv;
    }
}

internal class Person {
    public String name;
    public override string ToString() {
        return name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj is Person)
            return String.Compare(name, ((Person) obj).name, false) == 0;
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that example is it only works when editing a cell. The combos must be populated while the grid is drawn.

Comment: Ok - looks like event interception won't work (CellFormatting is not good for this purpose as it's fired almost continually).
 It has to be a completely manual creation of the grid and filling in the values. I'm experimenting.

Comment: What do you mean by event interception? In my experience, the most difficult part was getting the `DataGridView` to stop throwing exceptions by mixing values. `CellFormatting` is optional, but is the correct way to format your data. It's there for illustration purposes.

Comment: The event doesn't really matter. It's not possible to reference the controls in the cells anyway except in Edit mode, only the values. In other words, it's not possible to assign different datasources to each combobox in the grid while it's drawing.

Comment: I think the way I can work around this is to create all the datasources for all the different comboboxes, then create the datagridview in code like your example.

Comment: Ok - I'm an idiot. The cell.Value and what is displayed are different (DOH!).
The correction is:
cell.Value = cell.Items(0).ListID
NOTE: the ListID is defined by me so it won't show up in intellisense.
Silly Me.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Use the `DataBindingComplete` event handler to iterate through your rows and set the source for each `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`.

**Example**

Here's an example of how I did this. You'll need to add a `DataGridView` and a `ComboBox` (with two options, i.e. "option 1" and "option 2", for switching the `DataGridView.DataSource`) to your `Form`.

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Property Groups As List(Of Group)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.Groups = Me.InitializeGroups()

        Dim cbc As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        cbc.DisplayMember = "Name"
        cbc.ValueMember = "ID"
        cbc.HeaderText = "Matches"
        cbc.Name = "Match"
        cbc.Width = 150
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cbc)

        Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim examples As New List(Of Example)()

        If Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            examples.Add(New Example("Me", "blah"))
            examples.Add(New Example("You", "blah"))
        Else
            examples.Add(New Example("Him", "blah"))
            examples.Add(New Example("Her", "blah"))
            examples.Add(New Example("It", "blah"))
        End If

        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = examples
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataBindingComplete
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = TryCast(row.Cells("Match"), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
            cell.DataSource = Me.Groups.Where(Function(g) g.Members.Contains(row.Cells("Foo").Value.ToString())).ToList()
            cell.Value = cell.Items(0).ID ' Same property as combocell.ValueMember
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function InitializeGroups() As List(Of Group)
        Dim groups = New List(Of Group)() From { _
            New Group() With { _
                .ID = 1, _
                .Name = "All", _
                .Members = New List(Of String)() From { _
                    "Me", _
                    "You", _
                    "Him", _
                    "Her", _
                    "It" _
                } _
            }, _
            New Group() With { _
                .ID = 2, _
                .Name = "Them", _
                .Members = New List(Of String)() From { _
                    "Him", _
                    "Her", _
                    "It" _
                } _
            }, _
            New Group() With { _
                .ID = 3, _
                .Name = "Us", _
                .Members = New List(Of String)() From { _
                    "Me", _
                    "You" _
                } _
            }, _
            New Group() With { _
                .ID = 4, _
                .Name = "Me", _
                .Members = New List(Of String)() From { _
                    "Me" _
                } _
            }, _
            New Group() With { _
                .ID = 5, _
                .Name = "Human", _
                .Members = New List(Of String)() From { _
                    "Me", _
                    "You", _
                    "Him", _
                    "Her" _
                } _
            }, _
            New Group() With { _
                .ID = 6, _
                .Name = "Non-human", _
                .Members = New List(Of String)() From { _
                    "It" _
                } _
            } _
        }

        Return groups
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Example
    Public Sub New(foo__1 As String, bar__2 As String)
        Foo = foo__1
        Bar = bar__2
    End Sub

    Public Property Foo() As String
        Get
            Return m_Foo
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Foo = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Foo As String
    Public Property Bar() As String
        Get
            Return m_Bar
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Bar = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Bar As String
End Class

Public Class Group
    Public Sub New()
        Me.Members = New List(Of String)()
    End Sub

    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Id
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_Id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Id As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String
    Public Property Members() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return m_Members
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            m_Members = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Members As List(Of String)
End Class
```

Comment: I don't mind iterating again - good example. How do you show the DatagridViewComboBox's selected value?

Comment: actually, just needing the first item selected (selectedindex = 0).
Looking around the Internet to see how this is done. MS does not make this easy.
I got row.Cells("Match").Value = ??? part, but can't seem to get the first value of the combobox

Comment: ok - so far, it isn't possible to set the selected index of a dgvComboBox (ugh!), but possible to set the value of the cell itself that the dgvComboBox uses. So I'm close to the right answer.
I tried this, but it doesn't work :
            Dim itm As Group = DirectCast(cell.Items(0), Group)
            row.Cells("Match").Value = itm.Members(0).ToString

Comment: The error I get from using the code above: "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid."   24hrs of hair pulling and still no solution!

Comment: @MC9000 So close. Try `cell.Value = cell.Items(0).Name`.  I added this to my code example above and when run, it gave the desired results. TBH I thought it should have been `cell.Value = cell.Items(0)`, but *magic*.

Comment: I had to read your code again. So the "Member" is not the combobox list items and the "Name" is the list items. (for some reason, I thought the members would show up in the combobox).

Comment: I have a new problem, however. When assigning the datasources to my comboboxes (via a simple lookup method), it simply disappears once the form is displayed (even if I add the items with the .Add method). Not sure why this is going on, but in your example, it works - pretty much identical, except I am doing a lookup (I add 2 more code snippets above). The combos just lose their data (no errors). A mystery

Comment: Have you confirmed `Dim wpm_items As List(Of WPM_Item) = GetComboboxData(name, SKU)` returns items? I took your first attempt code (modified for my objects) and it ran just fine. I too am running DotNet 4.5.  I wonder if it's something to do with that call to get the needed data.

Comment: Yes it does. I think the datagridview is resetting the combobox's datasource in another event after the DatabindingComplete. Makes no sense to me - the only difference I can see is you have a hardcoded data.

Comment: Hmm, what other methods or events have you implemented dealing with the data source?

Comment: the DataSourceChanged for the DataGridView itself, but that isn't fired again after the DataBindingComplete event is fired. The odd thing is that the DataBindingComplete is called twice (in fact every event is doubled) - maybe this is due to autogeneratecolumns = true? I'll try manually creating the columns and set autogenerate to false.

Comment: OK, I created the grid via code and am able to set the datasource for each combobox, however, there seems to be no way to set the selected combobox item. cell.Value = cell.Items(0).Name does not work. cell.Value = wpm_items.Item(0).Name does not work. The following test I did also does not work:             Dim test As Object = wpm_items.Item(0).Name
                Dim NameStr As String = ObjToStr(test)
                cell.Value = NameStr